# I am creating a quiz and the variable is only storing half of the answer

Tags: python

I'm creating a quiz for my GCSE where a person is given the musical and the first letters of the song, they then must guess the entire song. The part I'm having trouble with is that even though I get the question right, it is telling me I am wrong. I'm also using a CSV file to store the questions and answers.

I have tried changing the variable many, many times and I'm really not sure what else to do. Currently the loop is still open, but the code is not finished yet and I cannot move on until I've done this.

```
while fail!= True:
    randomN = random.randint(0, totalQu - 1)
    musical = questions[randomN][0]
    title = questions[randomN][1]

    title_split = title.split()
    new = []
    for title in title_split:    
        letter=title[0].upper()   
        new.append(letter)    
    ans=" ".join(new)     
    print(musical+",",ans)
    answer = input()
    if answer == title:
        print("That is CORRECT")
        score = score + 3
    elif answer != title:
        print("That is INCORRECT. Try again")
```

If the question is "Dear Evan Hansen, F F" then the answer is "For Forever" but if I input this it tells me I am wrong. The variable 'title' is for some reason, only the first word? For example, in this case it would be "Forever".

Comment: What is the purpose of `ans`?

Comment: Also, `title` is a leaked loop variable. For your example question, a guess at the answer might be `"Forever"` instead i.e. the last word. In other words, `title = questions[randomN][1]` and `for title in title_split:` interfere with eachother

Comment: "The variable 'title' is for some reason, only the first word?". Strange, when I run your code I see that `title` is the _last_ word. This makes sense to me because `for title in title_split:` causes title to take the value of each word in turn, ending with the final word. Maybe I didn't provide the right values to all of the variables whose initialization you didn't show in your code sample. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: ahh sorry yes, you're right I should have put forever instead of for, I apologise

Comment: Ok, but that wasn't the take-home point from either of us. Rather, you want to pick a name other than `title` in `for title in title_split`

Comment: is there anything you suggest? I'm so sorry for being so unhelpful, I'm in the middle of exams and my brain is fried

Comment: Anything you like, provided it isn't `title`, a python keyword or some other name that already exists in your code. `for banana in title_split:` or `for George in title_split:` makes no difference. But you also didn't answer me about the purpose of `ans`, which you never use. We can't really test this locally so we're stuck with either suggestions, good guesses or building a whole test case ourselves.

Comment: So this worked but now (I need to use a different example, lets say Dear Evan Hansen, Waving Through a Window) the answer is correct the initials are wrong (in this case W W W W)? Also I'm not entirely sure of the purpose of ans, its something my teacher added and then never explained?